# How to delete all financial contributions via the API?

Tags: civicontribute, api

I want to create an extension to delete all financial contributions from the database. The database only contains simple contributions that are not tied to memberships or events.

The developers guide suggests using the Order API for adding, updating and deleting orders and the underlying financial entities.

However, when I try to delete an order using APIv3 explorer I get an exception 'Only test orders can be deleted'. In APIv4, the Order entity does not seem to exist.

What would be the recommended approach to delete the financial contributions via the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Contribution Delete API to delete the contribution.

[image]

Comment: Will this also delete the underlying financial data (line items, financial items, transaction items) associated with the contribution or only the contribution itself?

Comment: Yes it should...